# How to fix angular route not working on reload

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to get my router to work. Basically I have a home page at `/` with a router link to `/courses` which works perfectly but when I reload `/courses`(or type the address in) it takes me back to the home page and if I click on the router link again it takes me to `/courses/courses` which is the same as `/courses` but this seems wrong. Also if I type in `/courses/` then I get a 404 error.

I would really appreciate it if anyone has any advice on how to fix this!

```js
// app-routing.module.ts is:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses/courses.component';
import {ReviewsComponent} from './reviews/reviews.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'courses',
    component: CoursesComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'courses/:id',
    component: ReviewsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  CommonModule],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<h1>Course Reviews</h1>
<div>
  <nav>
    <a [routerLink]="'/courses'">Courses</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

```js
//courses.component.ts

import {Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CourseService } from '../services/course.service';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { AddCourseComponent } from '../add-course/add-course.component';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.css']
})

export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource  = [];
  responseArray: string;
  courseList = new Array<Course>();
  selectedCourse: Course;


  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
              private router: Router,
              private modalService: NgbModal) {
    this.courseService.newDataAdded.subscribe(
      (st: string) => {
        this.fetchCourses();
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchCourses();
  }

  fetchCourses(): void {
    this.courseService.getFirstPage().subscribe((data: Array<object>) => {
      this.dataSource  =  data;
      this.responseArray = JSON.stringify(data);
      const obj: MyObj = JSON.parse(this.responseArray);
      for (const i of obj.results) {
        const courseObj: string = JSON.stringify(i);
        const course: Course = JSON.parse(courseObj);
        this.courseList.push(course);
      }
    });
  }
  onSelect(course: Course): void {
    this.selectedCourse = course;
    console.log('selected course is ' + this.selectedCourse.course_name);
    this.router.navigate(['/courses', this.selectedCourse.id]);
  }
  onButtonClick(): void {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AddCourseComponent);
    modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      this.courseService.newDataAdded.emit('new data added successfully');
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}

interface MyObj {
  count: number;
  next: string;
  previous: string;
  results: Array<string>;
}
```

and the HTML file is:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courseList" (click)="onSelect(course)">
    <span class="badge">{{course.department}}</span> <a [routerLink]="['/courses', course.id]"> {{course.course_name}} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-med btn-outline-primary" (click)="onButtonClick()">Add a new course</button>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: try removing '/' in router link in html file i.e..,

<a [routerLink]="['courses', course.id]"> {{course.course_name}} </a>

Comment: Try [routerLink]="/courses" instead of [routerLink]="'/courses'" in app.component.html.

Comment: @Lindsey M can you please choose the right answer or tell the right solution for you, if you've solved it? I think there are some of the answers you got wrong here, but a (not) working example would be nice here. For example with StackBlitz or similar. Even if the question is outdated.

Answer (score 7):

If somebody is still looking for an answer for this issue (when reloading and getting error 404):
In your app-routing.module.ts where you define your routes, just add in the

```
@NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })]
```

In that case the code above would look like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,  { useHash: true }),
  CommonModule],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

credits:
https://medium.com/wineofbits/angular-2-routing-404-page-not-found-on-refresh-a9a0f5786268

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to be right but i think you miss something little - try to add empty path and redirect it to any path like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'courses',
    component: CoursesComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'courses/:id',
    component: ReviewsComponent
  },
  {
    path: ''
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

I think this piece of code is missing - check the scenario after adding this

If you are not using `HomeComponent` you can use `redirectTo: 'courses'` and `pathMatch: 'full'`

Happy coding :)

Comment: I've tried but it's treating http://localhost:4200/courses/ as if it's just http://localhost:4200 so when I reroute it, it just goes to http://localhost:4200/courses/courses again. Also the empty path makes it so that all the contents of the home page (just the header and router link right now) display twice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping your link with [ ] in your routerLink?

My app.component.html is:

```
<h1>UW-Madison Course Reviews</h1>
<div>
  <nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['/courses']"> Courses </a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check your index.html to see what is set for base href.
I had the same issue and setting:

```
<base href="./">
```

fixed the thing.
I know this post is outdated but may be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload a published page in Angular and receive a 404 error, it's because the server doesn't recognize the route.

Traditionally, the server looks for physical data that matches the requested URL. If none is found, a 404 error is returned.

###### Solution:

Create an `.htaccess` file and save it at the root level on your server.
The file *must* be named `.htaccess`.

The content of the file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]"
```